# Counting parent nodes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Is there a native method of DOM element in ECMAScript that will allow to count all ancestors of a given element (up to window object or DOM element specified by Id,Name etc.)?

Example use is to check all ancestors of a given element and remove a specified attribute.

Comment: Nope, you'd have to write it yourself; jQuery has a `.parents()` or `.parentsUntil()` method for that.

Comment: Don't confuse parents and ancestors.

Comment: Not a direct in-built function, but if you get a hold of a DOM node, you can then access the `parentElement` property. You can then just recursively go. Something like `var node = document.getElementById("myId");` and then `while (node != null) { node = node.parentNode }` would get you to the top

Comment: The window object is not a DOM element. Perhaps you meant the `html` element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've wrote a simple function that does an action described in a question. It gets all ancestors of a given element and removes a given attribute from every element that is between "starting" and "ending" element (it does not perform an removeAttribute method on "ending" element).

```
   var modifyAncestors = function(startingelementid,endingelementId,searchedattribute) {
        var nodecount = document.getElementById(endingelementId).childNodes.length;
        console.log(nodecount);
        var currentid = startingelementid;
        console.log(currentid);
        console.log(searchedattribute); 
        for(var i = 0; i < nodecount; i++) {
            if(currentid == endingelementId) {
            break;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById(currentid).removeAttribute(searchedattribute);
            currentid = document.getElementById(currentid).parentNode.id;   
            }
        }               
    }
```

Working example: http://www.blacktieseo.com/so/js/test.html (couldn't get it to work with Fiddle JS).

Any comments, bugs etc. will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of keeping the ID and then hitting the DOM for each lookup (admittedly, not a huge hit, but still), you can keep the node and do `while (node != null && node.id !== targetId) { /* your node manipulation */ node = node.parentNode;  }` Erm, yeah - taken (modified) from my comment to your question. I didn't see the answer you posted while I was posting the comment.

Comment: Actually, on second thought - what I said would be wrong - you are going the other direction - children instead of parents. My bad, I blame it on not enough caffeine. Still, I do think my approach is slightly better. The same principle applies - instead of looking up each child node by ID, you just traverse the DOM going `currentNode = childNodes[i]` It also solves the problem of potentially not having an ID for all nodes.

Comment: I was aware of that issue but didn't have time to actually modify that solution. Thanks for the tip will definitely use it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this "correct" solution does not work at all. Besides the erroneous assumption that all DOM nodes have IDs, and the poor design which mixes finding the ancestor elements with performing some action on them, consider the case where the ending element has only one child. The loop will then terminate after one iteration, even if the ending element has not been reached. What is the point of consulting `childNodes.length` on the ending element, and looping over that?

Answer (score 1):

There is the node iterator ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator ) which could be used for this purpose

Comment: Sorry but I was asking for native Javascript solution.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "native JavaScript solution". `document.createNodeIterator` is just another DOM API like `element.parentNode`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath:

```
document.evaluate('ancestor::*', x, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript for more details.